# Searching for video converter that maintains folder structure

Tags: video, video-editor, video-recording

I'm searching for video converter software that maintains folder structure. I have a lot of videos that store to their respective folder, but what I want is to convert the entire folder and subfolders and the output path will remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Most decent encoders with watch folder support have an option to automatically encode to the same folder structure that the source came from.  I'd check the listing of any software you are looking at to see if it supports it or try a demonstration copy.  I know that Adobe Media Encoder does.

Beyond that level of detail, this is a product recommendation question which is off topic since software may or may not be available tomorrow and the options for video conversion software change frequently.